# withstand voltage of RS-485 Transceiver

Tags: rs485, transceiver

i am working with a half duplex **RS-485 Transceiver** ic **SP3485EN** with 10Mbps Data Rate
datasheet :https://www.maxlinear.com/ds/sp3485.pdf
i actually want the **maximum working voltage (Viom)** of design purpose, but only  esd rating and supply voltage is mentioned in the data sheet is there a that i can find the **maximum working voltage**

Comment: What maximum working voltage you mean? There is no Viom in the datasheet?

Comment: i basically  can't figure out the withstand voltage of the transceiver

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by withstand voltage? Of what? Input voltage? Supply voltage? Output voltage? Compared to ground?

Comment: The voltage is 2.5V differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullet item under **FEATURES** says:

> -7V to +12V common-mode input voltage range

This range of voltages is mentioned many times in the tables describing the driver and receiver DC characteristics.

In other words, the receiver will work correctly (and the driver will not be overloaded) as long as both signal lines fall within this range, and the differential voltage between them is at least ±0.2 V.

Comment: It can withstand +/- 15V, but that is the absolute maximum rating. The range where it still operates normally is as mentioned above.